# Warning messages from kafka AdminClient

Tags: apache-kafka

whenever i run any kafka CLI tool i am getting following warning messages

```
kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server kafka-dev:9092 --command-config client.properties --list
[2021-07-14 07:02:31,595] WARN The configuration 'ssl.truststore.location' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
[2021-07-14 07:02:31,595] WARN The configuration 'ssl.keystore.password' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
[2021-07-14 07:02:31,595] WARN The configuration 'ssl.keystore.location' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
[2021-07-14 07:02:31,596] WARN The configuration 'config.providers.file.class' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
[2021-07-14 07:02:31,596] WARN The configuration 'config.providers' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
[2021-07-14 07:02:31,596] WARN The configuration 'ssl.truststore.password' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
__consumer_offsets
test-topic
```

command run successfully but warning messages are always printed.
how to fix it ?
my kafka version is 2.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These annoying WARN messages finally got resolved in 2.8.0 release

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-10090

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to "fix" if the `AdminClientConfig` doesn't accept those properties. If you remove them from the file, and you don't get an error, then that is one solution.

I recall seeing a JIRA around either suppressing these messages or passing though the [admin properties](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/admin-configs.html) correctly for the AdminClient

Comment: I think it was fixed in 2.8.0, so these annoying warnings won't come out